# JavaFx 8: update the current selected item of a ComboBox if it is modified

Tags: combobox, javafx-8, changelistener, observablelist

I have a `ComboBox` with a `ObservableList<Item>` as model. I can update, externally to it, the elements of the list and I want to update the current selected item of `ComboBox` if it's modified.
I tried to do:

```
private final ObservableList<Item> list;
private ComboBox<Item> comboBox;

....

comboBox.setItems(list);

comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

System.out.println("selected index: " + comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); );

ListChangeListener<Item> listener = new ListChangeListener<Item>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Item> c) {
                 while (c.next()) {
                        for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i) {
                            int selectedIndex = comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                            System.out.println("selected index: " + selectedIndex );
                             if (i == selectedIndex) {
                                comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(selectedIndex);
                            }
                         }
                     }
                 }
            };

            list.addListener(listener);
```

I added a `ChangeListener` to the list, so when some element in the `list` is updated, I can update the selected item in the `comboBox`. But this doesn't work 'cause `comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()` inside `onChange` returns me `-1` and I don't understand why (If I print the value out of onChange, for example the first System.out, the value is correct).

Can you explain me this behavior and if there is a better way to achieve what I want?
Thanks.

Comment: don't understand what you are after - in the code snippet you seem to re-select the already selected item ... why? Anyway, same procedure as always: please show a SSCCE to demonstrate your problem :-)

Comment: I re-select the selected item when this is externally changed. For example, if I have the combobox with a list of string A-B-C-D and selected item A. In my app I have a section where I can add, edit, delete the list. If I edit A in A1, I want that the selected item of the combobox reflects the change. Anyway I will try to create a simple example. Thanks @kleopatra :-)